# How do I use unicode in the WHERE clause of a query in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unicode-string

I have a table with Traditional Chinese strings in it, stored in an NVARCHAR2(100) field - for example

一定會

The table has been loaded from a comma-separated text file via the import dialogue in SQL Developer.

If I run

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1;
```

I can see

一定會

in the results.

However, if I try

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = '一定會';
```

I get zero rows. I've had a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm but don't see any explanation there.

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = N'一定會';
```

returns nothing, and neither does

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = TO_NCHAR('一定會');
```

Do I need to wrap the string in a function to tell Oracle to interpret the unicode as ... well, unicode?

Comment: Did you read what you linked to? *The TO_NCHAR function converts the data at run time, while the N function converts the data at compilation time. `INSERT INTO customers VALUES (1000, 
  TO_NCHAR('John Smith'),N'500 Oracle Parkway',sysdate);`*

Comment: Yes, but neither adding TO_NCHAR nor N made any difference. I'll amend the question to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you need to put a N before the first delimiter to tell the communication protocol that the following characters are in Unicode and therefore must not be translated/interpreted/converted, etc.  For example:

```
Where column1 = N'一定會'
```

You must not put any blank space between the N and the '

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that and it still returns no results.

Comment: Then it's probably because the column1 is not of type nchar, nvarchar or ntext.  Also, the fact that it is displayed correctly doesn't mean that it is stored correctly because an error in writing is often corrected by the same kind of error in reading.  For example, you can store this string in a varchar field with the right or the wrong encoding scheme but while it will still be displayed correctly, you won't be able to search against it.

Comment: column1 is nvarchar2(100) - is that a subtype of nvarchar, or will your solution be inapplicable?

Comment: Often, the error in translating is made by an intermediate layer such as a form on a web site.  You can check that the string has been correctly stored on the database by testing against it with the functions Unicode() et NChar().

Comment: I don't know the difference between nvarchar() and nvarchar2(); so even if I don't really think that this is the source of the problem, you should check it anyway.

Comment: Again, you need to use the function Unicode to check for the correcteness of the stored string:  Select Unicode (substring (column1, 2, 1)), Unicode (N'定')

Comment: I only get an "invalid identifier" response from Oracle if I use the unicode function - is that in 11.2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61737/discussion-between-jamesf-and-sylvainl).

Comment: I don't know Oracle, so the error might be either the use of Unicode() or of Substring().  This should be standard SQL but you should use the correct function for Oracle. You could also have made a typewriting error; impossible to tell without seeing the exact code that you have tried.